# Integrating galen with appium and getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented

Tags: java, appium, galen

I am trying to implement layout testing for Android Flipkart using Galen with Appium but galen throwing org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented

The code works fine for Selenium . I have changed the driver - Android Driver and used appium but it throws:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'RICHAKATHURIA', ip: '10.175.12.77', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {app: C:\Users\richakathuria\Inst..., appActivity: .activity.HomeFragmentHolde..., appPackage: com.flipkart.android, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: C:\Users\richakathuria\Inst..., appActivity: .activity.HomeFragmentHolde..., appPackage: com.flipkart.android, deviceName: moto g(7) power, newCommandTimeout: 300, noReset : false, platformName: android, platformVersion: 9}, deviceApiLevel: 28, deviceManufacturer: motorola, deviceModel: moto g(7) power, deviceName: ZF62248SXZ, deviceScreenDensity: 320, deviceScreenSize: 720x1520, deviceUDID: ZF62248SXZ, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 300, noReset : false, pixelRatio: 2, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 9, statBarHeight: 53, takesScreenshot: true, viewportRect: {height: 1318, left: 0, top: 53, width: 720}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 6c19f21f-333e-4fd7-817a-db2ead8eda60
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:489)
    at com.galenframework.utils.GalenUtils.resizeScreenshotIfNeeded(GalenUtils.java:189)
    at com.galenframework.utils.GalenUtils.takeScreenshot(GalenUtils.java:319)
    at com.galenframework.page.selenium.SeleniumPage.makeSimpleScreenshot(SeleniumPage.java:182)
    at com.galenframework.page.selenium.SeleniumPage.createNewScreenshot(SeleniumPage.java:175)
    at com.galenframework.page.selenium.SeleniumPage.getScreenshotFile(SeleniumPage.java:164)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayoutForPage(Galen.java:100)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:86)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:69)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:59)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:154)
    at com.galenframework.api.Galen.checkLayout(Galen.java:128)
    at GalenClient.pageLayoutTest(GalenClient.java:55)



        LayoutReport layoutReport = null;

        WebDriver driver = MobileDriverFactory.getDriver();//return AndroidDriver

        layoutReport = Galen.checkLayout(driver,
                CoreConfig.getInstance().gspecFilePath() + "\\" + gSpecFileName, groups);



        log.info("Layout" + layoutReport);
        generateHTMLReport(layoutReport, groups, testMethodName);
        getLayoutErrors(layoutReport, device.getName());

Expected : Galen should take screenshots and generate correct report.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below stpes

1.Update the java client library.

2.Use MobileElement mobileElement,@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AppiumDriver driver

Let me know if it helps for you.